# Is it possible to highlight the output of putty?

Tags: putty

I don’t know whether it is possible? Forgive me if it is silly.

I am using the putty. Where I will run scripts and scripts results large set of set of unorganized data. In which i have to search the data.

For instance in the large set of data retrieved i have to highlight or change the color of the font in the sentence which contains the text "`ERROR`"?

Answer (score 0):

> *"the large set of data retrieved i have to highlight or change the color of the font"*

- `hgrep` (highlight grep) provides such functionality.

  - http://acme.com/software/hgrep/
- using `vi`

  - `":set hlsearch"` highlight search keyword. but, when data is large, you should have enough memory to load whole data file